# Lebesgue integral iteration with the limit

Tags: lebesgue-integral

For every n, let $f_{n}:[0;1]\rightarrow{\mathbb R}$ a measurable Lebesgue function:  $\int_{[0;1]} {\left| f_{n}\right\| ^{2}}\mathrm{d}m\leq{5} 
$

Is true that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \int_{[0;1]} {\left| f_{n}\right\| ^{2}}\mathrm{d}m=0$? Is true that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \int_{[0;1]} {\left| f_{n}\right\|}\mathrm{d}m=0$?

Comment: Welcome to math SE. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2):

No.

Consider $f_n(x) = \sqrt{5}$ for all $x$ for all $n$.

Then $\int |f_n|^2 \mathrm{d}m \leq 5$, but both
$\lim \int |f_n|^2 \mathrm{d}m$ and $\lim \int |f_n| \mathrm{d}m$
are nonzero.

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: Thank you. So useful!

Comment: And if we added the hypothesis $f_{n}(x)\rightarrow{0}$ when $n\rightarrow{\infty}$ for every almost $x\in [0,1]$, would it be true?

Comment: @user857880 Please consider accepting a correct answer.